# How to calculate row-wise average of a 2-D numpy array of only non-zero elements and subtract average from the non-zero elements

Tags: python, numpy, collaborative-filtering

I am building a recommendation system. I am using NumPy arrays to represent users, where each row is a user and each column is a movie. I want to normalize each row by subtracting the average of each row from the non-zero elements (i.e from only those entries for which the user provided a rating). I have tried many ways to do this using np.where, np.nonzero() and so on but could not achieve exactly what I want here.
E.g I have the matrix

```
x = np.array([[0,0,1,2,3],[0,0,2,3,4],[0,0,3,4,5.0]])
```

I want to achieve the same effect as this

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    y = np.mean(x[i][x[i].nonzero()])
    x[i][x[i].
```

nonzero()] -= y

which outputs:

```
[[ 0.  0. -1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0. -1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0. -1.  0.  1.]]
```

but in a vectorized way, without using loop.

I have tried

```
mask = x!= 0
t = np.npwhere(mask, x-x.mean(axis=1).reshape(-1,1), x)
```

but this takes the average over the entire row, but I want to average over only the non-zero elements.

Comment: The 0s don't affect the row sum; divide that by the number of nonzero terms in the row.  You can do that for all rows at once.

Answer (score 0):

First compute **where** condition array (which elements to operate on):

```
wh = x != 0
```

Then compute the mean of the "wanted" elements:

```
mn = np.mean(x, axis=1, where=wh)[:, np.newaxis]
```

Note that `[:, np.newaxis]` converts a *1-D* result into a *2-D*
array with a single column.

Caution: *where* parameter has been introduced in *1.20.0* version of
*Numpy*. If you have older version, upgrade.

And to get the result, run:

```
result = np.where(wh, x - mn, x)
```

The result is:

```
array([[ 0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  1.]])
```